# Is L is the empty set, {$\emptyset$}, is it then true that LL = {$xx \mid x\in L$}?

Tags: automata, regular-language

My reasoning is that both LL and {$xx \mid   x\in L$} is equal to {$\emptyset$}. Is this correct?

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the empty set.

Comment: You're right, it should just be $\emptyset$ right?. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that if $L=\emptyset$, then $\{xx:x\in L\}=\emptyset$?

There is no $x\in L$ to begin with, so "$x\in L$" is always false; the second set is indeed empty.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Also, is this the only  language that has this property ie $LL = \{x^2:x \in L\}$